# How can I call this stored proceder in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, oracle11g

I'm a biginner at C# and ASP.NET, I've have a data schema on TOAD FOR ORACLE then i created a procedure to retrive an employee info by using cursor

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LE_SELECET_EMPLOYEE_CUR (EMPID IN INTEGER, EMPINFO OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)IS
BEGIN
  Open EMPINFO For 
   Select * From LE_EMPLOYEE
   WHERE EID = EMPID;
 /* Close EMP_INFO */
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END LE_SELECET_EMPLOYEE_CUR;
/
```

then i connect the code with the database by this code

```
 string oradb = "Data Source=****;User ID=****;Password=*****;Unicode=True";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("LE_SELECET_EMPLOYEE_CUR", conn);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

would you please show me how can i call this proceder?

Answer (score 1):

you just have to do like this next

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

but like to suggext dispose connect object once your done so code is

```
using ( OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
{
  conn.Open();
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("LE_SELECET_EMPLOYEE_CUR", conn);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  //read all data here 
  conn.Close();//optional as you are using using
}
```

Comment: this is a very broad question and you could do with reading a blog  i think this may help you

Comment: i searched about it, and i culdn't find a way how to call a curser, so this why i end up asking at STACKOVERFLOW. maybe it's bored for you but not for others :). @JackM

Comment: yes but the question is How can i read the data? sorry but i'm new at this @PranayRana

Comment: forgot to add the link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12509/difference-between-datareader-dataset-dataadapter-and-data.aspx